# get the expression value in ng-model

Tags: angularjs

My code is

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" name="tot" ng-model="myModel.tot"
 ng-init="myModel.tot = {{myModel.date1 | amDifference : myModel.date2 :'years'}} years"  
 required="required"/>
```

If {{myModel.date1 | amDifference : myModel.date2 :'years'}} years = 3 years, I need myModel.tot= 3 years. But am not getting it.

Please help me to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`ng-init="myModel.tot = {{myModel.date1 | amDifference : myModel.date2 :'years'}} years"`

To:

`ng-init="myModel.tot = {{(myModel.date1 | amDifference : myModel.date2 :'years'}}) + ' years'"`

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got what i need..

```
ng-init="myModel.tot = (myModel.date1 | amDifference : myModel.date2 :'years')+ 'years'"
```